# Failed to load Steamui.dll error

Tags: steam

I tried to install Steam on my PC today, and it didn't work due to the "*Failed to load Steamui.dll*" error.
Of course, I tried most of the solutions on the web, such as deleting and re-installing Steam, manually removing the *Steamui.dll* file and/or replacing it with one on the web, but these solutions didn't work. Every time I try any of these fixes, the same error occurs.
How can I fix this?

There are no Korean-named folders in the way, if you were wondering.

I also noticed something strange: when I was trying the fix where you delete the *Steamui.dll* and *Libswscale-3.dll* files, I noticed that my Steam installation didn't have the *Libswscale-3.dll*, but a *Libswscale-4.dll*, instead. I'm not sure if this is causing the problem, but I think this may be of importance. I didn't tamper with it just in case it would cause even more problems.

In the image below are the contents of my Steam's DLL folder.
Ignore the DLL named *originalsteamui* - it was what I was tampering with.

[image: Ignore the "originalsteamui", that's the steamui that steam installed itself but I renamed it so I wouldn't have to delete it]

Comment: Hi Hu sh, it would be easier if you just mention the current state of affairs, and not the things you were looking for and then found. Also: what's the premise here? You *tried* reinstalling something which is Steam, I presume, but why did you do so, and why are you stuck at *trying*? It would also be a lot easier if you describe what we're supposed to see in the screenshots, so it's easier to follow your already muddled story.

Comment: Oop sorry, let me make it clearer. As you can probably tell, I'm not the most mature...

Comment: Hope this edit cleaned up any confusions!

Comment: Yes, thank you. I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

- In most cases it's practical to start troubleshooting a malfunctioning program by **running it as an administrator** of your system.
  This is likely not the cause here, but it can help speeding up the process.
- **Temporarily disable any third-party** firewall, anti-virus **software** (Windows Defender usually plays nice, for a change), or [other intrusive software](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289), and try restarting Steam.
  Take caution, as this will also temporarily leave your system vulnerable, so be sure to re-enable directly after a problem is fixed (that is: disable only during that window of restarting Steam).
- **Try deleting that *Libswscale-4.dll* file**: it surely is a newer version of *Libswscale-3.dll*, and, in any case, if Steam is missing files, it will redownload them.
- There are a few more fixes explicitly for your case mentioned in [this Steam Community thread](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/648814845404204770/?ctp=10), most successful of which seem to be (or seems to be a combination of) **the following steps** [edited slightly for readability]:

  > All you have to do is [restart your computer in Safe Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/). Delete all of your Steam files other than the *AppData* folder and the *Steam.exe* file. Double click *Steam.exe* and it should successfully install the update.

  and

  > Fastest way, instead of redownloading after deleting the files in Safe Mode, is to [add the following parameters to your Steam shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/29569/how-to-add-command-line-options-to-shortcut): `-clientbeta client_candidate` (e.g. `"C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe" -clientbeta client_candidate`).

  Now, before you try this in Safe Mode, I suggest deleting the mentioned files - as administrator - in the *normal Windows mode*, creating a shortcut, adding those parameters, and running it - as administrator. If that doesn't work, you can always fiddle around in Safe Mode.

Comment: Thanks for the huge amount of help! I'll try them out and tell you the results.